# Dynamically adding a close button (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Trying to add a 'X' - close button for a google maps marker. The markers will show small on the map but will enlarge when clicked (same marker, just increasing the size). I can add a close button but cannot get it to work (reduce the size back to original). Solutions need to be dynamically added please.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gost1zLd/

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.width = '100px';
div.style.height = '100px';
div.style.background = 'black';

var img = document.createElement('img');
img.style.width = '100%';
img.style.height = '100%';
img.src = '';

var exit = document.createElement('div');

function large()
{
    div.classList.add("large");

    if (div.className == "large")
    {
        div.style.width = '300px'; 
        div.style.height = '300px';

        exit.innerText = 'X';
        exit.style.width = '20px';
        exit.style.height = '20px';
        exit.style.fontSize = 'xx-large';
        exit.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        exit.style.color = 'white';
        exit.style.position = 'absolute';
        exit.style.top = '5px';
        exit.style.left = '265px';
    }
}

function close()
{
    div.classList.remove("large");
}

document.body.appendChild(div);
div.appendChild(img);
div.appendChild(exit);

div.addEventListener('click', large, false);
exit.addEventListener('click', close, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that removing the class `large` is not enough to reset the `<div>` to its original state since class `large` in itself is meaningless because it has no CSS definition. My advice is to move the styling to CSS instead of JavaScript. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gost1zLd/1/.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Works perfectly. I didn't know about using the stopPropogation() method so thanks for pointing that out. Assume its to stop the click on exit registering as a click on the div?

Comment: It prevents the event to bubble up to its parent elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you make separate functions, you can use `start()` again in your `close()` function to reset the original style. I've refactored your code a bit, hope it's self explanatory:

```
function close () {
    div.classList.remove("large");
    start();
}
```

Only problem with your setup is you will rebind everything when you would call `start()` on `close()`. Instead, try to separate functionality and the issue becomes clear.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/sznnnouw/)**

Additionally you can optimize the dynamic styling with some helper functions.
You need a function to convert a literal object to a css string.
You need a function to extend objects, similar to jQuery's $.extend() in order to set the style at once ([doc](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_csstext.asp)) for both states (normal and large).

```
this.divStyle = convertLiteralToQs(cfg.div.style);
this.divLarge = convertLiteralToQs(extend(cfg.div.style, cfg.div.large));

this.div.style.cssText = this.divStyle; // normal style
this.div.style.cssText = this.divLarge; // large style
```

This will speed up the browser reflow for dynamic styling in JavaScript.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/ny687tje/)**

Using this approach you can now more easily "style your logic" cross referencing the [HTML DOM style object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp).